# Update edge property value using gremlin scala in titan + cassandra DB

Tags: scala, graph-databases, titan, gremlin, gremlin-server

I am trying to update an edge property value of outgoing Edges (outE) using gremlin scala.

Environment:
Titan + Cassandra

```
graph.V().outE().properties("Id","100").iterate()
```

Above is not working. Is there any other way to update the edge property value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a minor error. Your traversal is doing a lookup. To add the property to all the edges you do the following:

```
graph.traversal().V().outE().property("Id","100").iterate();
```

`property` mutates. `properties` does a lookup. More info [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#addproperty-step)